# Java - can't run program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't run HelloWorld in Eclipse - it shows message:

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.taksila.javabyexample.overview.HelloWorld, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.taksila.javabyexample.overview;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hi Planet");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Must be a hiccup in Eclipse. Try to rebuild everything and run it again.

Comment: Is the file in the correct subfolder? I.e. something like `src/com/taksila/javabyexample/overview` where `src` is marked as a Java Source folder in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you post a screengrab of your file structure in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is correct. Try to restart IDE or just save sketch :-)

Comment: I forgot that i need to save it before running, it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is definitely correct. Save it, restart the IDE, and wait to load all of its components. Then again run it!